# iOS app suddenly can't connect via HTTPS after IPv6 change

Tags: objective-c, xcode, server, nsurlsession, ipv6

and thanks in advance.

Everything was working great in my app, which is essentially complete. App was complete and custom VPS server was set up as backend.  Then, reading the Apple Submission guidelines, I ensured that my server was IPv6 compatible.

Now suddenly I cannot connect to my server over HTTPS.  It connects fine over HTTP still (if I go back and change the urls).  Further, I was able to connect over HTTPS before the IPv6 change.

Now I get this error in the Xcode console:

---NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)---

I've been reading other posts about workarounds, but I want to keep my app legit.  It was working over HTTPS earlier, and I don't see why the IPv6 change would cause this.  I know I can amend the app transport security key, but I want this ready for production, and I don't want a rejection from Apple.

It is not a self-signed certificate, and everything was fully functional before hand.

I contacted my server company, and their not sure what is the problem.

I'm using NSURLSession, and a typical connection looks like this (I have not implemented any NSURLSession delegate methods or customizations in anyway besides what you see below).

```
//VALUES TO BE POSTED
NSMutableString *post = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"u=%@&p=%@", username, password];


//PERCENT ESCAPE THE URL
[post setString:[post stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//CONVERT POST VALUES TO DATA
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];


//RETRIEVE LENGTH OF DATA FOR PURPOSES OF POST HEADER
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[postData length]];


//BUILD THE URL REQUEST
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];



//CREATE SESSION FOR SERVER CONTACT
NSURLSessionDataTask *sessionTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


 AND SO ON....
```

Comment: Your code looks pretty straightforward. I'd suggest asking on StackOverflow's sibling site serverfault.com how to verify that your IPv6 + TLS setup is correct and working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the error code, I'm pretty sure your server is configured incorrectly in IPv6 mode and isn't serving the complete certificate chain (missing or incorrect intermediate certs).  I can't confirm that, of course, without knowing the server's name, but you can check it with:

```
openssl s_client -connect host:443
```

and see what it says.  Of course, if it tries to connect by IPv4... you might have to use the IPv6 address instead of a hostname.  I've never tried s_client with IPv6, so YMMV.  :-)

Comment: I appreciate your response.  I will look into those things now and get back to you.  Is setting up a VPS to IPv6 something everyone goes through, or am I doing something unnecessary in the first place.  I mean, I saw it on the Apple Submission Guidelines, but it seems like it isn't a topic many people discuss.

Comment: I ran the command as you suggested.  I get the following error: "getaddrinfo: Name or service not known.  connect:errno=2"

Comment: Technically, your server doesn't *have* to support IPv6.  When iOS 10 gets an IPv4-only answer, it will transparently construct a special address that routes the traffic through an IPv4-over-IPv6 tunnel.  You do, of course, have to test your app to make sure it works in that environment.

Comment: so it's probably best to just continue in this course and problem solve this error, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Or just switch off IPv6 on the server, remove the AAAA record, and be done with it.  Either way.

Comment: I just don't get it.  I read that I had to ensure IPv6 because the Apple Review Team tests on a IPv6 only network.  

Others on SO mentioned how they got rejected because of this.  I don't understand why I would have to add IPv6 if it would just reroute to IPv4 as you said.  

I just want the quickest and most secure fix.

Comment: Also, I tested the server with  # openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1.  I received "verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate" AND "verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate".

Comment: You've really been helpful.  I've read your other SO answer on How to test if an app supports IPv6.  My app does not have any hardcoded IP addresses.  So, in light of the Apple Review Team stating they use IPv6 only networks, would it be best to revert the changes on the server and allow the rerouting to occur, or continue forward, as you mentioned in your last comment. I have no preference either way.  My goal is to avoid app rejection and delays in review process.

Comment: @ARENV You will eventually need IPv6 on your server anyway, so you may as well keep it. The thing that you need to fix is the server's TLS misconfiguration.

Comment: In iOS documentation, it is said that the server shouldn't have to listen ipv6, we can made changes in our own API by using high level classes like NSURLSession. Though NSURLSession is used, still the issue persists. Any idea regarding this?

Comment: That's likely an unrelated issue.  Ask a new question and include code snippets.

Comment: I have been waiting to resolve the issue with my hosting company, but it's still not resolved.  That's why I haven't marked the answer as correct or not.  But It's given me a lot of leads, so I'll mark it as correct.  When the problem is finally resolved, I will update this post.  Thank you for your help @dgatwood